# python dictionary with one key and multiple values

Tags: python

I have a list like: `somelist= ['a','b','c','d']`
I want to have a python dictionary with key as `"key1"`and values `'a','b','c','d'` from some list.

`d={}`

`for l in somelist:`

`d["key1"]=l`

returns only {key1:'d'} but not values as the list.

How do i do this?

Comment: `d["key1"] = somelist`.

Comment: `d['key1'] = somelist`?

Comment: A better question is "How did you do this now?"  Show us so we can help you.

Comment: @roippi : I get invalid syntax print d['key1']=somelist
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user1189851 Remove the `print` statement, Python is not PHP. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
for l in somelist:
```

you are looping through each element of `somelist`. In this case, each element is a string, so when you do:

```
d["key1"] = l
```

you are assigning the current element as the value for the key `"key1"` of the dictionary `d`. On each iteration, this value will be overwritten, so at the end, you will only have one element, the last one `'d'`.

**What can you do?** Just assign the whole list as the value:

```
d["key1"] = some_list
```

there is no need to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Assing? Never seen that one before. :p

Comment: @Human sorry I'm not native English speaker, edited (:

Answer (score 2):

You are looping through the list and assigning a new value to the same key each time.

One way to assign several values to a single key would be to assign the list to that key:

```
d["key1"] = some_list
```

And then access the elements using the index:

```
>>> d["key1"][0]
>>> 'a'
```